# Have to click twice on button to get function running, Should work in one click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have to click "start" button twice to get the success response function of my Ajax to work. I want it to work in one click.

This is for a gaming website which sets up a new cookie once the game is click via PHP Ajax and when the cookie is set, the success data is sent and new window with cookie data is opened.

*Javascript:*

```
$(document).on('click', '#startPlay_btn', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();


$.ajax(
{
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {'csrf_token': $('#csrf_token').val(), 'flag': 1},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {           
        if(data.response==1)
            window.open('play.php?gameID='+data.gameID, '_self');
    }
});

});
```

*ajax.php:*

```
switch ($_POST['flag'])
    {
        case 1:
            //generate game ID and CSRF 
            $c_value = $base->recursive_generator('b_gameID', 1, 'balances');
            if( !isset($_COOKIE['gameID']) )
            {
                setcookie('gameID', $c_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  
                $_COOKIE['gameID'] = $c_value;



                $base->insert('balances', array('b_gameID'=>$c_value));

            }   
                echo json_encode(array('response'=>1, 'gameID'=>$_COOKIE['gameID']));

            break;
```

I expect new window to be opened once I click start button after setting up cookie in the browser, but I have to click the button twice, when clicking first : it sets up the cookie, and when clicking again, it opens up the window.

Comment: Can you try to log something in the console within the scope of the event? Maybe just log (e). So you can see if it reaches that part

Comment: You should check what **exactly** is returned in the first AJAX call. Does it already contain the expected response? Is that parsed correctly? You could dump `data` in your `success` callback to inspect that

Comment: @KoenHollander : Just tried that, Had to click twice again in order for success function to run console.log("message"); 

Ajax is doing its work in 1 click --> It's sending the post request to ajax php and setting up the cookie, but I have to click again in order for my success function to work. Either Ajax isn't sending the success request after setting up the cookie or I don't know !

Comment: Can you try to manually fire the click event? (Like $("#foo").click(); or something) - does that work within 1 try? https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @NicoHaase On first click no data is returned from ajax post back but the cookie is being set as it should in my php code. Then NOTHING.
On second click, the success data is being returned successfully. 

I don't seem to figure out why it's not being returning success in just one click as it should.

Comment: @KoenHollander Yes that does work indeed in one click.

Comment: Have you checked which parts of that PHP code are run in the first click and why? Within the posted code, there is nothing else that could be executed....

Comment: @ShreyalRana Maybe you can use this as a workaround to fire the click event when you click on the button with the onclick attribute?

Comment: @NicoHaase Everything in the php : IF (!isset($_COOKIE['gameID']) ) () works in the first click. 

It runs because there's no cookie set and I am trying it after clearing my cookies,

If cookies are however present, the button works in a single click !